# Hibernate's ddl-auto = validate and column default values

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I get Hibernate to validate column default values (via `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate`) when it is starting up?

**UPDATE**

- From my analysis I only see Hibernate evaluating a column's type and nothing more. See: `org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable()`
- If I want to validate information like default values I'd likely have to write my own code, going through the metamodel of Hibernate's entities and the database tables.

---

**Main issue:**

- When there is a mismatch between the default value definitions in a Hibernate entity and what the actual database's default value setting is, Hibernate does not throw an error during bootup. I was expecting to see an error. How can I ensure it gets thrown?
- When there's a mismatch in datatype of a column, Hibernate throws an error on bootup (that is a good thing).

Below I'll explain all the details. **You can probably just look at the code snippets and catch on to what I'm trying to get across.**

---

**Details: MariaDB command line**

I created a MariaDB table via:

```
CREATE TABLE `person2` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT 27,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I use the mysql command line and manually run an insert statement, the new record's `age` is set to 27 (expected behavior):

```
insert into person2 (name) values ('Bob')
```

I can also explicitly provide an age, and it accepts the provided value (expected behavior):

```
insert into person2 (name, age) values ('Joe', 21)
```

---

**Details: Hibernate**

I'm using Spring/Hibernate and I made the following class to map to the `person2` table:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person2")
@DynamicInsert
public class Person2 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Type(type = "text")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ColumnDefault("27")
    @Column
    private Integer age;

    // Normal getters/setters:

    public void setName(String val) {
        this.name = val;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer val) {
        this.age = val;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

In order to generate some test data on Spring startup, I have the following:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseLoader {

    @Order(1)
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner createTestData(Person2Repository person2Repository) {
        Person2 person2 = new Person2();
        person2.setName("hibernate: Bob 10");
        person2Repository.save(person2);

        ...

        return args -> {
        };
    }
}
```

At first glance everything looks fine: a row gets added to the database with the right `name` and `age`=27

---

**Hibernate negative tests:**

I want to make sure Hibernate's `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate` is working properly. So I did the following:

I changed age's type from Integer to Long inside the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person2")
@DynamicInsert
public class Person2 {
    ...

    @ColumnDefault("27")
    @Column
    private Long age;
}
```

As expected Hibernate threw the following error:

- Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [age] in table [person2]; found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [bigint (Types#BIGINT)]

Cool, I wanted that error thrown. Then I wanted to test another scenario: cause a mismatch in the column default value settings. However, when I made the modification seen below, I didn't get an error on startup (this is *not what I expected*):

```
public class Person2 {
    ...

    @ColumnDefault("999")
    @Column
    private Integer age;
}
```

Hibernate didn't even throw an error when I but in a bogus default value (non-numeric):

```
public class Person2 {
    ...

    @ColumnDefault("asdf")
    @Column
    private Integer age;
}
```

So I thought let's try the `columnDefinition` technique of setting the default. Again, I used a bogus value (see below) and Hibernate did not throw an error (this is *not what I expected*):

```
public class Person2 {
    ...

    @Column(columnDefinition = "asdf")
    private Integer age;
}
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change to `create` or `update` and see what will happen then.

Answer (score 0):

First you should know how the defaults are used in database columns. `default` values is set in a column when there is no values while saving a record into that column which means if you are saving a record and some of the property or columns does not have values and you have configured default values then in that case default value is set to that column otherwise set the column values available at the time of saving records.

if let's say you have column1 and default value is 10 then while writing records to tables then
`if column1 is not null then write the value of column1 else write default value 10`